# Getting the direction of manipulation delta

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, direction, delta

In my project, it is possible to move an object (rectangle...) across the screen using the delta manipulation, as below:

```
rectangle.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
rectangle.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
```

How can I get the direction (right, left, up, down) when the object is moved?
I need to get this information while the object is moved.

Answer (score 0):

What is `e.Delta.Translation.X`, `e.Delta.Translation.Y`? Don't you mean...

---

`e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X` 
`e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y`

And what the heck is `rectangle.TranslateX`, `rectangle.TranslateY`?

These things don't exist.  A quick google of what you want to do shows you a lot of working examples.

For example, moving an Image around the screen with Touch

---

```XAML
<Image x:Name="myImage" Source="/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png" Stretch="None" ManipulationDelta="myImage_ManipulationDelta">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform></CompositeTransform>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

---

```C#
private void myImage_ManipulationDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    Image i = sender as Image;           
    CompositeTransform ct;
    if (i.RenderTransform is CompositeTransform)
    {
        ct = (CompositeTransform) i.RenderTransform;
        ct.TranslateX += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
        ct.TranslateY += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
    }           
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think I got the answer. 
Getting the starting point of the object (in this case the rectangle), when finished object movement, just get the ending point and subtract the initial, If I get a negative value is left to x and if you stay positive is right, similarly for y.
I am using the Windows Phone 8.1 platform, there is not much about Google.

Comment: Windows Phone does not support e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.x; e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;

Comment: @AlessonDanilo WP8 does support e.DeltaManipulation, your question indicated that you're using WP8 (check your tags).  If you're using 8.1 then tag your question correctly otherwise state your platform  explicitly.  We can not read your mind.